# How to set up AWS SNS to send Push notifications to list of Android devices

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I have followed the documentation of AWS SNS push notification. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-dg.pdf

I have successfully send Push notification to android device via GCM, But I am sending only one android device at a time. (To sending multiple devices I have to run the same code again and again via for loop)

So my question is :
Is there any way to send push notification for multiple android device at the same time. (Means is there any API, any method who took multiple device token (registration id) as a List or Array and send the push notification to all Android device)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Subscribe the devices via the SNS client to a topic and then publish your message to the topic. All devices subscribed to this topic will receive the notification.

Subscribing to a topic:

```
String subscriptionId = snsClient.subscribe(new SubscribeRequest()
            .withEndpoint(endpointId)
            .withProtocol("application")
            .withTopicArn(topicId)
            ).getSubscriptionArn();
```

Publish notification in a topic:

```
PublishResult result = snsClient.publish(topicArn, message);
```

Comment: SNS doesn't have a batch send API. As described in this answer, have your devices subscribe to a topic. Then SNS will broadcast a notification to all subscribers.